# Does React's onLoad event on images work "reliably"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In React documentation, an `onLoad` event is listed under "Image Events" without much fanfare. Compare to jQuery's documentation for `.load()` with its long list of caveats, and the need for libraries like https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded.

My question is whether the `onLoad` event in React suffers from the same caveats as in jQuery, or does it handle all the edge cases and eliminate the need for libraries like one referenced above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked the source code looking for any kind of extensions to this event and as far as I can see React doesn't extend this API in any way, it just "mirrors" it - React's `onLoad` is basically the same thing as regular `Image`'s `onload` that you could use without React.

So - yes, it suffers from the same caveats, it doesn't handle corner cases and doesn't eliminate need for external libraries.